# Limit to max records to be searched in Elastic Search Group by query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a strange issue where data for one of our customers has a lot of records based on certain field x. When the user triggers a query for the group by for that x field, the Elastic Search cluster is going for a toss and restarting with OOM.

Is there a way to limit max records that elastic search should look for while aggregating the result for a certain field so that cluster can be saved from going OOM ?

PS: The group by can go on multiple fields such as x,y,x, and w, and the user is searching for the last 30-day data only.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sampler Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) with terms aggregation if you wish to restrict the number of documents that should be taken into account for an aggregation (let's say terms aggregation) (in this case)

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "role": "example",
    "number": 1
}
{
    "role": "example1",
    "number": 2
}
{
    "role": "example2",
    "number": 3
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "sample": {
            "sampler": {
                "shard_size": 2              // Max documents you need to have for the aggregation
            },
            "aggs": {
                "unique_roles": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "role.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "sample": {
            "doc_count": 2,                           // Note this
            "unique_roles": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "example",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "example1",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Raj did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)